# Javascript date/time operator

Tags: javascript

I want to implement +/- functionality in date/time in Javascript.

Here is example.

```
var now = new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:36:45 EST 2012");
console.log(now + 3min);
```

How can I do this?
Is there any example like this?

Comment: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1197928) and [How to add 20 minutes to a current date?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4517672) and [How do I subtract minutes from a date in javascript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/674721)

Comment: thanks.it is working.